# Remove border of Jquery Mobile´s grid

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I am using Jquery Mobile´s grid and I want to remove the default border and change the default background-color. Here is my code:

```
   <div class="ui-grid-b">
    <div class="ui-block-a"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="height:60px">Block A</div></div>
    <div class="ui-block-b"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="height:60px">Block B</div></div>
</div><!-- /grid-b -->
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is

```
.ui-bar-a {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
border-style: none; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.ui-bar-a {
background-color: #fff !important;
border-style: none !important;
}
```

`!important` helps to override the jquery mobile css.